# no Video Flash Player back

Tags: playback

The flash  videos is not working.

I tried to disable hardware acceleration but this did not work

Here is a picture . hardware driver is Unknown.

Guess I can't post a pic wow. they say a picture is worth a thousand words I guess not on this post.

Comment: more info please. browser? ubuntu version?

Comment: 12.04 LTS 32 bit. Firefox.

Comment: When you say "not working" what do you mean? What happens? If you go into your plugins and check to see if they are up to date, what do you see?